# How to get all data using left join in LINQ

Tags: linq

when i am trying to join two list as left join it throws exception string null exception

```
 enter code here
                   public void LeftJoinPerson()
                    {
                       lstPerson = new List() { 
                                   new Person(){ id = 1, name = "A" },
                                   new Person(){id = 2,name = "B"},
                                   new Person(){id=3,name="C"},
                                   new Person(){id=4,name="D"}
                   };
```

```
        lstPersonDetail = new List<PersonDetals>() { 
                             new PersonDetals() { pid = 1, mobile = 
                             9685745285, address = "Address1" },

                             new PersonDetals() { pid = 2, mobile = 
                             9685745285, address = "Address1" },

                             new PersonDetals() { pid = 3, mobile = 
                             9685745285, address = "Address1" } 
        };

        var dataLeftJoin = (from a in lstPerson
                               join b in lstPersonDetail on a.id equals 
                               b.pid into c
                               from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new {
                               a.id,
                               a.name,
                               d.mobile,
                               d.address,
                               d.pid
                               }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a question. Step 1 is: check the location of the null reference. Did you do that? Having done that is usually doesn't take much to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

In Left Join the right hand table may not have data, so need to check for null while creating a new select type.

Try below:

```
var dataLeftJoin = (from a in lstPerson
                               join b in lstPersonDetail on a.id equals 
                               b.pid into c
                               from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new {
                               a.id,
                               a.name,
                               mobile = d == null ? 0 : d.mobile,
                               address = d == null ? "" : d.address,
                               pid = d == null ? 0 : d.pid
                               }).ToList();
```

Comment: still throws exception :An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in LINQ.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: its work when both collection have same count but  when left collection have greater than right collection its throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
var dataLeftJoin = (from a in lstPerson
                           join b in lstPersonDetail on a.id equals 
                           b.pid into c
                           from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new {
                           a.id,
                           a.name,
                           mobile = d == null ? 0 : d.mobile,
                           address= d == null ? null : d.address,
                           pid= d == null ? 0 : d.pid
                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: can you try change address= d == null ? null : d.address, to address= d == null ? "" : d.address,  ?